# How to make a PHP Calendar with future months and dates?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, calendar

Okay, so I have a website I am creating, and I have a calendar made with HTML.

http://screencloud.net/v/b1OD

I want to add raquo's to the left and right of where it says (January 2013), so the user can browse the future and past months. How can I achieve this, along with making it update every month? Anyone have any ideas? It's coded in pure xHTML and CSS.

Long story short: How can I make this update the calendar monthly automatically? Also, how can I browse future and past months? (jQuery maybe?)

Thanks a lot,
IntactDev

Comment: Do you want a server side solution or a client side solution? Just pure HTML won't cut it here.

Comment: I would prefer a server side solution (if by server side, you mean it'll update the current month automatically); and I wasn't planning on using pure HTML, but I just designed it how I wanted it, then code the functions later on.

Comment: So then, have you tried anything? Where are you stuck? What's the problem? We won't write the entire thing for you...

Comment: No, haven't started yet. I just want to know how I can go about doing this @deceze

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Matthew--there are literally 100s... and in general if you can avoid re-inventing the wheel--do so. If you want something that will look good with your layout, check these out:

http://amsul.github.com/pickadate.js/themes.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here is a php calendar. http://keithdevens.com/software/php_calendar  Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

There are literally hundreds of Javascript calendars to choose from. This site here actually has a category for it: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cutindex1a.shtml

I suggest googling something like `css javascript calendar`. That can give you your controls, etc. Then you need to figure out how you will be passing your dates (AJAX calls or page post backs to load the data from different months). Either way, if you start with a JavaScript calendar (and layout) you like, it will get you on the right path.

Note: most calendars you will see will be date-pickers for filling forms, but even these can be easily adapted if you find one you like.

Comment: I would like to use my current design, hence why I asked how I could go about using my HTML & CSS layout.

Comment: Grab a JS calendar with the functionality you like and merge it with the CSS / HTML you are using to create your calendar.

Comment: Suppose I used this: http://calendarview.org/ how would I be able to unavailable event dates have like a red background, or a red number to indicate they're unavailable?

Comment: Looks good to me - not you need to style it to match your design and determine how you will interact with it (i.e. assuming you are showing events on it, is that an AJAX call when the user loads a new month or a post-back to reload the page with the new data)

Comment: Also - I like the DatePicker linked by @jnunn

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at AJAX/jQuery?  It has functionality for a date-picker:

[Datepicker jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

**Edit1:** You will probably need to edit the CSS to use your own color scheme or images, but I think it'll cover all your needs.

**Edit2:**

You can use the jquery.com based CSS or download, change, and reference them locally.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to learn it thoroughly.  You just download the AJAX/jQuery files, add them to your project, and add the DatePicker AJAX/jQuery code to your page.